# getline() error. no instance of overloaded function matches argument list.

Tags: c++

Hi i am trying to use getline() function by giving two arguments to it. but it is giving error as no instance of overloaded function matches argument list.

Here is my code snippet:

```
    string equation;
    cout<<"Enter the string";
getline(cin, equation);
```

can anyone please tell me if i am missing something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably another function called `getline` which takes different arguments. To use [the one you want](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), you have to

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```

and either use

```
using namespace std;
```

or explicitly put `std::` before `string`, `cout`, `cin` and `getline`.

Comment: ...or add `using std::string;`, `using std::cout;`, `using std::cin` and `using std::getline;`.